# System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x800706BE) when getting contact.LastName

Tags: c#, .net, outlook, mapi, comexception

Some of our users are getting this exception sometimes (not for every contact):

```
System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x800706BE): 
   The remote procedure call failed. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x800706BE)
   at Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook._ContactItem.get_LastName()
```

This happens when we're trying to get the last name of a contact (of the `ContactItem` type).

Does anybody know what the problem is?

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Hi Andrei can you post some code.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It is a Windows error, facility code 7.  The last word gives the Windows error, 0x6be == 1726:

```
// MessageId: RPC_S_CALL_FAILED
//
// MessageText:
//
// The remote procedure call failed.
//
#define RPC_S_CALL_FAILED                1726L
```

Interop with Office programs like Outlook happens through out-of-process COM.  RPC is the low-level Remote Procedure Call mechanism.  There are several reasons for such a remote call to fail.  Both the error code and the error name google well.

The simplest explanation is just that Outlook fell over.  That happens.  The advantage of in-process interop is that when the host program crashes then it will take out your code as well.  Not in an out-of-process scenario, you just get a hard to diagnose error.  Ask your customer's IT staff to use their typical Office troubleshooting strategies.

Comment: If you got here because of Excel Interop it is probably because of "FoxitReader PDF Creator COM Plugin" see : https://stackoverflow.com/a/44639653/4645236

Answer (score -1):

set the full access to Network Services (or identity of apppool) to the folder C:\Windows\System32\config\systemprofile\AppData

Regards!
Gabriel from Argentina