# Excel Interop Workbooks.Open inconsistencies

Tags: c#, excel, excel-interop

I have a process that is opening multiple workbooks

```
var exApp = new Excel.Application(); 
Excel.Workbook ONE;
Excel.Workbook TWO;
Excel.Workbook THREE;
ONE = exApp.Workbooks.Open(ONELocation);
TWO = exApp.Workbooks.Open(TWOLocation);
THREE = exApp.Workbooks.Open(THREELocation);
Console.WriteLine("All Excel workbooks opened successfully\n");
```

Sometimes it runs with no issues.

Sometimes though I get the following exception on crash

> System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: 'The remote procedure call failed. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x800706BE)'

The exception happens on different workbooks and sometimes not at all. When it happens after rerunning a few times the process goes through successfully and all data is processed correctly.

Why does it work sometimes and not others? Is there a better way to open these workbooks? How do I stop this from happening?

Comment: Your question is likely a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4471787/system-runtime-interopservices-comexception-0x800706be-when-getting-contact-la

Comment: Possible duplicate of [System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x800706BE) when getting contact.LastName](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4471787/system-runtime-interopservices-comexception-0x800706be-when-getting-contact-la)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`RPC_S_CALL_FAILED` was indeed the root cause as pointed out by the [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4471787/system-runtime-interopservices-comexception-0x800706be-when-getting-contact-la) user xxbbcc linked to as a possible duplicate.

However, that just told me the cause and did not solve the problem. 
I googled `RPC_S_CALL_FAILED` with the word excel and found this [SuperUser question](https://superuser.com/questions/1124945/excel-interop-remote-procedure-call-failed-or-rpc-e-serverfault)

I disabled the **"FoxitReader PDF Creator COM Add-in"** as described in the question and my program now runs consistently without error.

> How to disable the plugin: Excel > File > Options > Add-ins > Manage, then choose "COM add-ins" > Go. And then untick the problematic plugin.